# Regex grouping and matching

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a regex https://regex101.com/r/PPbhRn/1. Here i see that when "and" is captured, i am able to see some white spaces also captured above. Is there any way to get rid of that white spaces? and i want to know whether the pattern will match only when grouping is captured correctly?

```
String validRegex="(((?:[(]* ?[a-z][a-z]+ ?[)]*)|[(]* ?(NOT) (?:[(]* ?[a-z][a-z]+ ?[)]*) ?[)]*)( (AND|OR) ((?:[(]* ?[a-z][a-z]+ ?[)]*)|[(]* ?(NOT) (?:[(]* ?[a-z][a-z]+ ?[)]*) ?[)]*))*)";

    String formula = "mean AND trip OR (mean OR mango) AND (mean AND orange) OR mango AND (test OR NOT help)";
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(validRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = p1.matcher(formula);

    boolean result=MarketMeasureUtil.isValidFormula(formula);
    System.out.println(result);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            System.out.println( matcher.group() + "starting at" + "index" + matcher.start()+ "and ending at index" +matcher.end() );

        }
```

I'm not able to capture the groups properly, i need to capture groups like "mean AND trip" "OR" "mean or mango"..etc..
isValidFormula() invokes the regex.matches(). In our case matches works fine. Grouping is not working as expected

Comment: Only the full match contains those spaces. Group 2 is just 'and' always...

Comment: i need a regex which captures strings like (apple AND pineapple OR (egg) AND (pineapple)) where i have constraints like a word should be followed by a predicate "AND/OR" and also it should capture the groups porperly. If i try regex which is matching the above im not able to capture groups properly..is there any way to sort out? @marekful

Comment: Please edit your question and show the actual problem and Java code you have tried.  Regex is slightly different for every language/tool, so I don't think we should answer based just on a Regex101 link.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen edited

Answer (score 0):

Regex are not suitable for this task. I doubt that it's even possible to validate the expression if you can add as many braces as you would like to.

You have to write a parser which builds the tree, using a class like:

```
class Node {

    boolean[] isAnd = null;
    Node[] children = null;
    String literal = null;

    Node(String literal) { // creator for literals
      this.literal = literal;
    }

    Node(boolean[] isAnd) { // creator for intermediate nodes
      this.isAnd = isAnd;
      children = new Node[isAnd.length + 1];
    }

}
```

And the method would look like this:

```
Node parse(String) throws ParseException { // returns the root
```

First you can remove the superfluous braces on the right and the left side by counting all braces, then you can find the 0-level `and`s and `or`s (i.e. those that are not in braces) and create an intermediate node, if you don't find any 0-level `and`s and `or`s then the string has to be a literal or it is invalid. If it is an intermediate node then you add the children by calling the `parse` method recursively with the substrings surrounding the 0-level `and`s and `or`s.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you created some kind of DSL.
You should consider using a parser or implementing your own if your "language" is not complex.

I assume you just evaluate OR/AND operations. It is very similar to code a calculator where AND (multiplication) takes precedence over OR (addition). Therefore you could implement your own.
You can first tokenize the statement and validate it but don't try to do both at the same time with regex.  If validating is the only purpose you can end here.
Next if you have to evaluate the expression you can create a binary tree with the tokens (OR operand as left leaf and AND operand as right leaf for instance) and apply your grammar to evaluate the expression.

Comment: no i just need to validate the expression, i dont want to evaluate it. I need the paattern to be like "(apple AND (ornage OR kiwi))" . regex.matches() part works fine for mw. But im not able to undestand grouping